# Относительные пути в package.json для node_modules

Tags: node-modules, package.json

Есть папка с сайтом, который частенько приходится переносить. При переносе вручную приходится исправлять параметр "_where" файла package.json в каталоге node_modules. Есть какой вариант настроить относительные пути?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пока что есть такое решение https://www.npmjs.com/package/removeNPMAbsolutePaths
Подробная дискуссия тут https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10393
Тут открыт вопрос об удалении абсолютных путей https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/12110

Как видите - вопрос старый и пока не движется вперед.